# How to make a dynamic modal in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to open a modal when I click on a card, and this modal contains more informations about the card content that was clicked.

Here in my example, the cards are replaced by buttons.

So here how to change the modal content depending on the button clicked ?

I saw this post : [Change react-modal data dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514563/change-react-modal-data-dynamically). But I don't understand his solution.

App.js :

```js
function App() {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState({ show: false, data: null });

    const openNoWebsite = () => {
        setModal({ show: true, data: { title: 'No website in sight', subtitle: 'Having a website in 2021 is essential.' } });
    };

    const openMoreMoney = () => {
        setModal({ show: true, data: { title: 'More money', subtitle: "You think you have an awesome product, but people don't really notice it and your sales numbers are not going up."} });

    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setModal({ show: false, data: null });
    };
   return {
   <div className="main">
      <button className="solidText" onClick={openNoWebsite}>
      Button 1
      </button>
    <button className="solidText" onClick={openMoreMoney}>
      Button 2
      </button>
      {modal.show && modal.data && <Modal closeModal={handleCloseModal} />}

   </div>
   }
}
```

Modal.jsx :

```js
function Modal({ closeModal, data }) {
    return (
        <div className="modal-container">
            <div className="modal">
                <button className="btn btn--close" onClick={() => closeModal()}>X</button>
                <div className="modal__body">
                    <h1 className="modal__title">{data.title}</h1>
                    <h2 className="modal__subtitle">{data.subtitle}</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <span>How I will help you :</span>
                        <li>Discover together your goals through a strategy session</li>
                        <li>Discuss about the possible solutions to implement</li>
                        <li>A glorious online presence a.k.a. website</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="modal__footer">
                    <p>Wanna put your business out there ?</p>
                    <button className="btn btn--main">LET'S TALK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You add a state variable to your App component that is named something like `selectedCard` or someting, and based on that value you can render different stuff in the modal.

Comment: @hellogoodnight I update my code what I did wrong ?

Comment: You can do a modalState object that contain a show (to know when to open the modal) and data property, so when you click on a button/Card you can update the data accordingly to what you want to display.

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier can you show an example as response ? I'm really new to react and struggling a little

Comment: Just did it, tell me if you have any question

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier I update my post, I have the error "TypeError: data is undefined".

Comment: You didn't pass it as props to your component

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier what do you think about the solution I used ?

Comment: It's a way of doing it but you will need to rebuild what you want to display everytime you use it, not so dynamic. There is no best solution, it depends on what you want to display and how much you want to abstract your Modal

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to use a state that contain the data you want to show inside your Modal, usually what I do is that I create a state `const [modal, setModal] = useState({ show:false, data: null })` and when I press a button I update data accordingly to what I want to show.

Here I used car caracteristic put you can put whatever you want (description, big text, etc...).

The state show is not really usefull but I prefer to use it for clarity (you can just check if !data to know if you want to open or not your modal)

Example

```
function Modal({ closeModal, data }) {
  return (
    <div className="modal-container">
      <div className="modal">
        <button className="btn btn--close" onClick={() => closeModal()}>
          X
        </button>
        <div className="modal__body">
          <h1 className="modal__title">
            {data.name} {data.color}
          </h1>
          <h2 className="modal__subtitle">Having a website in 2021 is essential.</h2>
          <ul>
            <span>How I will help you :</span>
            <li>Discover together your goals through a strategy session</li>
            <li>Discuss about the possible solutions to implement</li>
            <li>A glorious online presence a.k.a. website</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="modal__footer">
          <p>Wanna put your business out there ?</p>
          <button className="btn btn--main">{data.name}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState({ show: false, data: null });

  const openAudi = () => {
    setModal({ show: true, data: { name: 'Audi', color: 'red' } });
  };

  const openBMW = () => {
    setModal({ show: true, data: { name: 'BMW', color: 'blue' } });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setModal({ show: false, data: null });
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <button className="solidText" onClick={openAudi}>
        Button Audi
      </button>
      <button className="solidText" onClick={openBMW}>
        Button BMW
      </button>
      {modal.show && modal.data && <Modal closeModal={handleClose} data={modal.data} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Super ! thanks I understand like this. But I think that putting the data content in the app is not really beautifull. Don't you think it's better to put it in the modal component or maybe to have the data in a json file ?

Comment: Usually you can get it from your API or some other source yes

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, not sure if it's the best but it work.

```js
const [modal, setModal] = useState({ show: false, requestedModalId: 0});

const handleOpenModal = (id) => {
    setModal({ show: true, requestedModalId: id });
};

const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setModal({ show: false });
};

return {
    <div className="main">
        <button onClick={() => handleOpenModal(1)}>Button 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleOpenModal(2)}>Button 2</button>
        {modal.show && modal.requestedModalId === 1 && <Modal closeModal={handleCloseModal}>
           <div>Modal Child 1</div>
        </Modal>}
        {modal.show && modal.requestedModalId === 2 && <Modal closeModal={handleCloseModal}>
           <div>Modal Child 2</div>
        </Modal>}
    </div>
}
```

```js
function Modal(props) {
    return (
        <div className="modal-container">
            <div className="modal">
                <button className="btn btn--close" onClick={() => props.closeModal()}>X</button>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```